# react-picky how to include the "Select all" in the Filter?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I'm using react-picky ([react-picky](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-picky)) in a project and liking it a lot. One quick problem is: once I use the "Filter" field, the "Select All" option disappears. I want to ultimately have the "Select All" while using the Filter, so I can select all the filtered options.
Can anyone help me accomplish that? Thank you so much!

Comment: in the answer below just only to keep Select All appear, but still need to fix when you filter sill select all can select the whole list, for this reason, look for the example I attached how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

very nice tool, I found there is if(multiple && !filtered) {...} 
all you have to do remove the condition && !filtered then select all still appear.here an [example](https://codesandbox.io/embed/simple-example-multi-and-single-select-2rttc):

```
          <Picky
          value={this.state.arrayValue}
          options={bigList}
          onChange={this.selectMultipleOption}
          open={true}
          valueKey="id"
          labelKey="name"
          multiple={true}
          includeSelectAll={true}
          includeFilter={true}
          dropdownHeight={600}
          renderSelectAll={({
            filtered,
            tabIndex,
            allSelected,
            toggleSelectAll,
            multiple,
          }) => {
            // removed && !filter from the condition to keep select all appear
            if (multiple ) {
              return (
                <div
                  tabIndex={tabIndex}
                  role="option"
                  className={allSelected ? 'option selected' : 'option'}
                  onClick={toggleSelectAll}
                  onKeyPress={toggleSelectAll}
                >
                  <h5>SELECT ALL</h5>
                </div>
              );
            }
          }}
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

This is now available out-of-the-box, by using the `selectAllMode='filtered'` prop.

This will both show the "Select All" box when filtering and ensure that only the filtered options are selected.